# Big Query: extract a certain number of signs after a text

Tags: extract, google-bigquery

my Database has two columns and looks like

> Name/   Description
>
> Anna/   Home, TEL:123-45678, Fax:123-45679
>
> Ben/    School, no phone,no FAX
>
> Clair/  Job,TEL:987-65432, Fax:987-45679
>
> Dave/   Home, TEL:147-85236, no FAX

I want eventually to get only those guys who have a phone number and the respective number.
Should eventually look like

> Name/   Description
>
> Anna/   TEL:123-45678
>
> Clair/  TEL:987-65432
>
> Dave/   TEL:147-85236

But to now all my tries with left() or right() were no much successful.

like

> right(Description, 13)

but this only worked if phone number was the last entry in all the strings.

Also

> left(Description, 13)

does not result well, since the phone number is not in the beginning.

Thank you!

Comment: Please add your tries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The regular expression extraction functions would let you do it, i.e.

```
select regexp_extract(
   'Clair/ Job,TEL:987-65432, Fax:987-45679', 
   r'TEL:(\d\d\d-\d\d\d\d\d)')
```

(note that the regexp pattern is prefixed with 'r' to make it a raw string literal)